# No ejecuta punto de interrupción en proyecto C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una duda estoy queriendo ejecutar un punto de interrupción de un proyecto ASP.NET MVC 5 pero al llegar a la linea de código no se ejecuta el punto de interrupción que le coloqué. Debo modificar alguna configuración adicional?

Adicionalmente verifique mi web.config y  tengo "debug=true".
He confirmado que la ejecución del aplicativo debe pasar por ahí pues descarte con otros puntos que deseo interrumpir y no se activan.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Clean && Rebuild.

Comment: Si lo intenté pero sigue igual

Comment: intenta cerrar visual studio y abrirlo nuevamente

Comment: Si lo intente pero persiste el inconveniente, no logro depurar el proyecto. Tengo otros donde si depura sin incovenientes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo me funcionó, tenia la opción OPTIMIZAR CÓDIGO activado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuidado que estás cambiando la configuración de Debug a Release.